# instead of looping through my list the execution stops after first item

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm not sure why instead of looping through the entire list called link my code stops after first item

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

with sqlite3.connect("911.db",timeout=10) as connection:
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT url FROM Links")


for link in c:
    print link
    page = requests.get(link[0])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    status = soup.find_all('div', class_='flashmessage warning')
    if not status:
        print "for sale"
        update_row = link[0]
        c.execute("UPDATE Links SET last_seen = (?) WHERE url == (?)", (today, update_row) )
    else:
        print "sold"
        update_row = link[0]
        print update_row
        c.execute("UPDATE Links SET status = 1 WHERE url == (?)", (update_row,) )
```

When I delete this section below I can print the entire list within the loop

```
if not status:
    print "for sale"
    update_row = link[0]
    c.execute("UPDATE Links SET last_seen = (?) WHERE url == (?)", (today, update_row) )
else:
    print "sold"
    update_row = link[0]
    print update_row
    c.execute("UPDATE Links SET status = 1 WHERE url == (?)", (update_row,) )
```

I don't understand why as soon as the "if not" or "else" statements match a value my loop stops.

It must be a very stupid mistake but I really can't find it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop over what is in `c`; inside the loop, you change `c`, so you can no longer loop over it.

Comment: Thank you Scott I've stopped looping what is in c: and the for loop is now going through all its values